# Laptop LCD Screen Flickering

Tags: laptop, troubleshooting, lcd

I recognize this is most likely not a software error and likely lies in one of the hardware components.

However, about 3 months ago I replaced the LCD screen on this laptop. The company which I bought it through provided a 12 month warranty. Before I contact them, I would like to verify that the problem **is** most likely the LCD screen and not the inverter.

As a side note, I have discovered that sometimes, if I unplug the power source to the machine, the monitor will switch off. Reconnecting the power source will fix the monitor.

Any comments? I recognize its impossible to diagnose hardware remotely, but it would be nice to know if there is a high probability it could be a component other then the LCD screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can scientifically say (e.g. happens every time) that unplugging power and plugging back in fixes the problem, it most likely is down to hardware and probably not directly the screen - could be some sort of problem in the power unit.

However, as you said, it is really hard to diagnose hardware remotely. it could be the inverter or as simply as a loose cable.

Comment: I actually believe now that the screen going off when the power is unplugged is due to a lid switch issue. I'm looking into that.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note (primarily to show up in Google search results), if you are looking for the location of the lid switch on a DV6000 laptop, it magnetic and to the left of the power button on the bezel.